# Is there any way to know which process is using memory in EC2 if I can't connect via ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

last night I receive an error log (I use Rollbar) from my server with the message "NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory"

When I was able to access my server, it took a lot, but I could connect by SSH. Sadly, every command I ran (free -m, top, ps, etc) I got "cannot fork: Cannot allocate memory".

Now I can't even access the server, I get "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"

This happened before and I just rebooted the machine, but now I want to know what is happening in order to prevent this to happen again. It's a m3.medium (with Ubuntu) and host a staging env, so I think it shouldn't have memory problems.

I wonder if is there any way, in the AWS Console, to see what is happening or free some memory in order to at least be able to connect via SSH.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the CPU utilization from the Monitoring tab?

Comment: Yes, when the problem starts it reached 100%. But now it's 20%

Comment: There is nothing you can do from the AWS console to affect individual processes or free any memory on the operating system running on the EC2 instance. You would have to SSH into the instance to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have no idea what the problem is then write a script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/var/log/memoryproblem.log
date +'%c' >> $FILE
free -m >> $FILE
ps axu |sort -rn -k 4,5|head >> $FILE
```

make cron run this at regular intervals

This will log quite a lot of information so clear up on a regular basis

Oh and another thing.  There is one way of seeing log information on a host apart from ssh.  In the aws console view of ec2 instances, select the instance and right click, instance settings -> system log may possibly be useful in this situation

Another thing to do is to temporarily increase the instance size.  m3.medium only has 3.75GB of ram.  If you up it to a m3.extralarge with 15GB of ram then it is possible the problem will occur and you can see what is going on due to the extra resource.  Once you've fixed the issue you can go back to a smaller instance

Comment: Thanks for the log idea, i'll crate the script.  For the moment I just reboot the instance because I couldn't wait any more.